# Google Analytics API from localhost

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Working on a php script to pull data from Google Analytics with the Google PHP Client API. I've got the script set up at localhost/ga/.

Got my API keys all set up, Analytics API turned on.

In "Client ID for Web application":

```
REDIRECT URIS  http://localhost/ga/
JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS http://localhost
```

In "Key for browser application":

```
REFERERS  http://localhost/*
```

Double checked all keys,ids, and secrets. But I'm getting this error:

```
"(403) There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
```

My current code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('GA Test');
$client->setClientId($cred['id']);
$client->setClientSecret($cred['secret']);
$client->setRedirectUri($cred['redirect']);
$client->setDeveloperKey($cred['api_key']);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    echo '<a class="login" href="'.$authUrl.'">Connect Me!</a>';
} else {
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
    try {
        $optParams = array(
            'dimensions' => 'ga:source,ga:keyword',
            'sort' => '-ga:sessions,ga:source',
            'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic',
            'max-results' => '25'
        );
        $dump =  $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:52371304',
            '2015-01-01',
            '2015-03-01',
            'ga:sessions',
            $optParams
        );
        var_dump($dump);
        echo 'hi!';
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Bah.

The Public Key I generated was the browser key not the server key. You can leave the IPs field blank and it will work with localhost.